# Суффиксы глагола

Tags: орфография

Почему в словах "затмевать", "ночевать" пишется буква Е перед ударным суффиксом -ВА-?

Comment: @irina19, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В ваших примерах суффиксом является не " ва", а " ева". См.: напр.: Грамматика русского языка. В. В. Виноградов.

Дополнение.

Правило.

Пишется в неопределенной форме и в прошедшем времени,
если в форме 1-го лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени глагол оканчивается на -ую(-юю):

совет***(ую)*** → советовать, советовал, советовавший ;
гор***(юю)*** → горевать, горевал, горевавший
суффикс -***уй-*** чередуется с -***ова- (-ева-***):

совет-уй-у  -  совет-ова-ть, совет-ова-л.

Не путать с глаголами, у которых ударный суффикс ***-ва***- сочетается с предшествующей гласное е- или и- (см. -ва-).

акая корневая гласная, в отличие от суффиксальной, сохраняется в неопределенной форме у глаголов без суффикса -ва- (см. -ва-):

обве-вАть → обве-ять, обви-вАть → обви-ть, зали-вАть → зали-ть, преодоле-вАть → преодоле-ть;
Внимание:

***проведывать (проведываю), но проповедовать (проповедую), исповедовать (исповедую); разведывать (разведываю), отведывать (отведываю), наведываться (наведываюсь), выведывать (выведываю); заведовать (заведую).***

Различать написание глаголов

увещевАть (ударный суффикс ***-ева-)*** и усОвещивать ( безударный суффикс ***-ива-***)

```
Суффикс -ва в глаголах всегда ударный;
Не путать глаголы с суффиксами -ева-, -ива- с глаголами, у которых ударный суффикс -ва- сочетается с предшествующей гласное е- или и-.
Корневая гласная е- или и-, в отличие от суффиксальной, сохраняется в неопределенной форме у глаголов без суффикса -ва-, т.е. перед -ва- у глаголов несовершенного вида
сохраняется та же гласная, что и в парных глаголах совершенного вида:

обве-вАть(что делать?) →обве-ять(что сделать?), обви-вАть→обви-ть, за ли-вАть→зали-ть, преодоле-вАть→преодоле-ть;
```

***Искл.: застревать (но застрять),
    затмевать(затмить), продлевать (продлить),  растлевать (растлить) – ударный суффикс -ева-;  намереваться, увещевать******

Comment: но ведь "ева" суффикс безударный...

Answer (score 1):

1 Затмевать-затмить.

Глагол затмевать связывается с темнеть и темненье – состояние по глаголу. Глагол затмить не является производящей основой к затмевать. Предположительно была форма *затьмневать с дальнейшим выпадением редуцированного Ь и упрощением группы согласных МН-затмевать;

или другая версия: были формы *затметь(от тьма) /* затмить(непереходный/переходный-как "темнеть" самому и "темнить" кого-то) с последующими образованиями затмевать / затмивать,но потом "затметь" исчезло, устарело, а несов.вид обеих форм совпал под влиянием других слов с суфф. – ева-, где суфф. выпадает.

2.-суфф. -ева-

Ноч/ева/ть-ноч/ую. С помощью суффикса -ова-/-ева- производятся глаголы от бессуффиксных имен существительных: горевать, рисковать, торговать, воровать, плутовать, тосковать, столоваться, пировать, расходовать и т. п. В 1-м  л. ед. ч. наст. вр.эти суффиксы выпадают (чередование с нулевым суфф.) -ую, -юю; 3-е л. мн. ч. -уют, -юют).